# OpenPDF shrink PDF

Tags: java, pdf, openpdf

**Setup**:
Creating OpenPDF from multipage TIFF with adding each TIFF page as com.lowagie.text.Image

```
...
com.lowagie.text.Document pdfDocument = new com.lowagie.text.Document();
com.lowagie.text.Image image01 = getPage(pageNumber);
document.add(image01);
...
```

**The Problem**: The file size

**Question**: How to reduce file size?

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps someone out there. I used following

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper.setFullCompression();
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper.getWriter().setFullCompression();
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setFullCompression();
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setCompressionLevel(com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION);
```

And instead using

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(((java.io.File) singlePageTiff).getAbsolutePath());
//or
Image image = Image.getInstance((java.awt.image.BufferedImage) pageImage, null, forceBlackAndWhite);
```

I used a compressed Image

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage pageImage = ...
int width = pageImage.getWidth(); 
int height  = pageImage.getHeight();
boolean reverseBits = false;
int typeCCITT = com.lowagie.text.Image.CCITTG4; 
//see com.lowagie.text.Image.CCITT_BLACKIS1; 
int parameters = 0;          
byte[] data = ((java.awt.image.DataBufferByte) pageImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Objects.requireNonNull(data);
int[] transparency = null;
byte[] g4 = com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.CCITTG4Encoder.compress(data, width, height);
com.lowagie.text.Image image = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(width, height, reverseBits, typeCCITT, parameters, g4, transparency);
```